# Finding the Closest Permutation Matrix Given Two Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, permutation-matrices

You are given two vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is there a method to find a permutation matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $M\vec{a}=\vec{b}$? Let us break this down into two cases:

1. The vectors are indeed related by a permutation of their elements, such that: $\vec{b} = M \vec{a}$. In fact, it is possible that there are many permutation matrices which satisfy this equation. For example, let $\vec{a}=(3,1,0,0)^\top$ and $\vec{b}=(0,3,1,0)^\top$, then we would like something of the form of the "shift matrix":
   $$
   M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   \end{bmatrix}.
   $$
   Although it is indeed also possible that
   $$
   M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   as we only have information about the images of the first two basis vectors. Is there a general algorithm that provides the "solution set" to this type of problem?
2. Now for the real problem I would like to solve. There is no permutation matrix $M$ such that $\vec{b} \not = M \vec{a}$. We wish to find an $M$ nonetheless, by finding the "closest" such permutation matrix: $\operatorname*{argmin}_M ||\vec{b}-M\vec{a}||$.

Any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question: If $\vec a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $\vec b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, we need to find the image of every basis vector $\vec e_i$. For $\vec e_1$, you can pick any $j$ with $b_j=a_1$ and then map $\vec e_1\mapsto \vec e_j$ (i.e., $M\vec e_1=\vec e_j$, i.e., the $(j,1)$ entry of $M$ is $1$, or the value of the desired permutation $\pi$ evaluated at $1$ is $\pi(1)=j$). Continue with this method, but avoid repetition, i.e., when looking for $M\vec e_i$, pick any $j$ with $b_j=a_i$, but only among those indices you haven't picked yet.

For the second question: We mainly have to decide which *value* in $\vec a$ to associate with which value in $\vec b$. And then, in case of repeated values on either side, their corresponding indices may be permuted at will. First let us find *one* such association that is optimal.

**Claim.** If permutation $\pi$  minimizes $f(\pi):=\sum_i(a_i-b_{\pi(i)})^2$, then there exists a permutation $\sigma$ such that $$\tag1a_{\sigma(1)}\le a_{\sigma(2)}\le\ldots\le a_{\sigma(n)}$$ and $$\tag2b_{\pi(\sigma(1))}\le b_{\pi(\sigma(2))}\le\ldots\le a_{\pi(\sigma(n))}$$

*Proof.* There are certainly sorting permutaions $\sigma$ that guarantee $(1)$. But for each such $\sigma$, there may exist indices $\ell$ with $b_{\pi(\sigma(\ell))}>b_{\pi(\sigma(\ell+1))}$ (whereas of course $a_{\sigma(\ell)}\ge a_{\sigma(\ell+1)}$).
Among all $\sigma$ with $(1)$, consider one that minimzes the number of such bad indices $\ell$. If no suc $\ell $ exists, w are done. So assume otherwise.
Let $j=\sigma(\ell)$, $k=\sigma(\ell+1)$, $\pi'=\pi\circ (j\;k)$. Then
$$\begin{align}  f(\pi')-f(\pi)&=(a_j-b_{\pi'(j)})^2+(a_k-b_{\pi'(k)})^2-(a_j-b_{\pi(j)})^2-(a_k-b_{\pi(k)})^2\\
&=(a_j-b_{\pi(k)})^2+(a_k-b_{\pi(j)})^2-(a_j-b_{\pi(j)})^2-(a_k-b_{\pi(k)})^2\\
&=-2a_jb_{\pi(k)}-2a_kb_{\pi(j)}+2a_jb_{\pi(j)}+2a_kb_{\pi(k)}\\
&=2(a_j-a_k)(b_{\pi(j)}-b_{\pi(k)})\\
&\le 0\end{align}$$
with equality iff $a_j=a_k$. By minimality of $f(\pi)$, we conclude that $a_j=a_k$. But them $\sigma':=(j\;k)\circ \sigma$ is a permutation that sorts $\vec a$ and has one less bad index than $\sigma$, contradicting our choice of $\sigma$. Hence the claim follows. $\square$

Now to find all optimal permutatons, you may permute arbitrarily among indices where components of $\vec a$ are the same, or similarly for components of $\vec b$. Note that considering only permutations among the components of $\vec a$ or  only permutations among the components of $\vec b$ will not necessarily give you all optimal solutions. On the other hand, permuting both with $ßvec a$ and within $\vec b$ may count some solutions repeatedly, namely when ranges of equal value "overlap" in the sorted order of the components of $\vec a$ resp $\vec b$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the link between your "Claim" and the algorithm. You you mean that the order of the values implies the correct permutation?